# Does argparse support multiple exclusive arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have two groups of arguments. You can use any number of arguments from each group but you cannot mix arguments between the groups.

Is there a way to customize conflicting arguments in `argparse` module? I've tried using method `add_mutually_exclusive_group` but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, argparse doesn't support that usecase out of the box. You'll have to check for that separately.

Comment: is there a module that can do this?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @user3056783: Never used myself, but docs look promising: [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/4/)

Comment: Please provide an example set of options to clarify why `add_mutually_exclusive_group` doesn't suit your needs.I suspect you are heading in the direction of needing sub-parsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've proposed a patch (or rather patches) that would let you test for general logical combinations of arguments.  `http://bugs.python.org/issue11588`.

The core of my ideas there is to add a hook just inside `parse_args` that lets the user test for all logical combinations of arguments.  At that it point it has access to a list `seen` arguments.  This list is not available to you outside `parse_args` (hence the need for a hook).  But with appropriate `defaults`, you can write your own tests that use the `args` Namespace.

The difficulties with implementing a general `argparse` version include:

a) implementing some sort of nesting groups (in your case several `any` groups nesting within a `xor` group)

b) displaying those groups in a meaningful `usage` line

For now your best bet is either implement your problem with subparsers (if it fits), or do your own testing after parsing.  And write your own `usage`.

Here's a sketch of a generalizable test that could be applied to the `args` namespace after parsing

```
def present(a):
    # test whether an argument is 'present' or not
    # simple case, just check whether it is the default None or not
    if a is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# sample namespace from parser
args = argparse.Namespace(x1='one',x2=None,y1=None,y2=3)

# a nested list defining the argument groups that need to be tested
groups=[[args.x1,args.x2],[args.y1,args.y2]]

# a test that applies 'any' test to the inner group
# and returns the number of groups that are 'present'
[any(present(a) for a in g) for g in groups].count(True)
```

If the `count` is 0, no groups are found, if `1` one group has been found, etc.  The `hook` that I mentioned in the bug issue does the same sort of testing, just using a different `present` test.

The normal `mutually exclusive` test would object if count `>1`.  A required group would object to `0`, etc.  You could also do something like

```
if (present(args.x1) or present(args.x2)) and 
   (present(args.y1) or present(args.y2)): 
   parser.error('too many groups')
```

ie. some combination of `any`,`all`,`and`,`or`.  But `count` is a nice way of handling the `xor` condition.