# Argparse: How to disallow some options in the presence of others - Python

Tags: python, parsing, command-line, argparse

I have the following utility:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do some action.')
parser.add_argument('--foo', '--fo', type=int, default=-1, help='do something foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar', '--br', type=int, default=-1, help='do something bar')
parser.add_argument('--baz', '--bz', type=int, default=-1, help='do something baz')
parser.add_argument('--bat', '--bt', type=int, default=-1, help='do something bat')
```

However, if the `--foo` option is used, the `--bat` option should be disallowed, and conversely, the `--bat` option should only be used if `--bar` and `--baz` are present. How can I accomplish that using `argparse`? Sure, I could add a bunch of `if / else` blocks to check for that, but there's something built-in `argparse` that could do that for me?

Comment: Using [mutually exclusive groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) will get you some of the way there...

Comment: Have you throught about the `usage` line that explains these constraints?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes of course, but I don't have anything barring people from doing so.

Comment: I explore the issues of implementing nest groups of arguments that handle various logical combinations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29925709/901925

Answer (score 3):

You can create mutually-exclusive groups of options with [`parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--foo', '--fo', type=int, default=-1, help='do something foo')
group.add_argument('--bat', '--bt', type=int, default=-1, help='do something bat')
```

, but for more complex dependency graphs (for example, `--bat` requiring `--bar` and `--baz`), `argparse` doesn't offer any specific support. That'd be going too far in the direction of the [inner-platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect), trying to rebuild too much of the full generality of a complete programming language within the `argparse` subsystem.